# vim - how do I cut some lines of file-1 to file-2 in 1 step?

Tags: paste, selection

When I need to cut some lines from one file to another file, I always do the following steps:

- Select the lines in file-1
- `:w >> file-2`
- Re-select the lines
- `d`

This is super annoying if you need to do it for like 10 times.

So, is there anyway I can write the selection to another file and delete the selection in the same time?

Edit: maybe using `gvd` to reselect and delete is a faster option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it a one liner using a range:

```
2,3w >> b | 2,3d
```

And if you want to keep doing this with visual selection, you can select the lines and then use `'<` and `'>` for the range:

```
'<,'>w >> b | '<,'> d
```

**Edit** To address the questions in comments:

- If the file you're trying to write doesn't exist you can use `w!` to force the command
- The `|` character is used to chain commands (not unlike `&&` in bash), you can read about it at [`:h :bar`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3Abar):

  ```
                          *:bar* *:\bar*
  '|' can be used to separate commands, so you can give multiple commands in one
  line.  If you want to use '|' in an argument, precede it with '\'.
  ```

Comment: As a command: `command! -range -complete=file_in_path -nargs=1 Wd <line1>,<line2>write >> <args> | <line1>,<line2>delete _`

Comment: Thank you, this works! But there is one issue: if file b does not exist, vim will return an error (`E212: Can't open file for writing`). Also, 1) Can you please explain what `|` do in the command? 2) typing `'<,'>` is not faster than reselect and delete with `gvd`.

Comment: For error, use `w! >>`. The bar is a command separator.